# Update Xcode 5.1.1 GM Seed

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5.1

I got Update mail regarding **Xcode 5.1 to Xcode 5.1.1 GM Seed** ( I'm enrolled in Apple Developer Program) That-

> This is a pre-release update to Xcode 5.1, which you can download from the [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) or [Mac Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action). Please note, this release can be used to compile and submit apps to the App Store and Mac App Store. Read the seed note for more details.

I'm trying to download from both of the above two resources, but could not see any update.

Please if you could find it, How to do. Share it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you login with your developer ID at the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

[image]